# what is the variance of this distribution function?

Tags: probability

this might seem a little stupid but I am uncertain how to find $E(x)$. I need to do it using the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

$$ F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x<0\\ x/2 &\mbox{if } 0 \leq x<1\\ 2/3 &\mbox{if } 1\leq x<2\\ 11/12 &\mbox{if } 2\leq x<3\\ 1 &\mbox{if } 3\leq x \end{cases}$$

the problem I have is that it is not a step function. I am not sure how to solve it.

In one calculation I got to : $ E(x)=\frac{7}{6}$ In another I got to $E(x)=\frac{71}{144}$.

can someone please give me some guidance?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write the density as $$f_X(x)=\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}1_{\{0\le x<1\}}+\frac{1}{6}\delta(x-1)+\frac{1}{4}\delta(x-2)+\frac{1}{12}\delta(x-3)$$So, the expectation is $$\int_{0}^1 x\frac{1}{2}dx+1\cdot \frac{1}{6}+2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+3\cdot \frac{1}{12}=\frac{7}{6}$$

Since $dF(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}1_{\{0\le x<1\}}dx+\dfrac{1}{6}\delta(x-1)dx+\dfrac{1}{4}\delta(x-2)dx+\dfrac{1}{12}\delta(x-3)dx$, using Riemann Stieltjes integral you'll get $\int xdF(x)$ which will be the same thing i.e. $\dfrac{7}{6}$